# Is Elaticsearch good for documents with few words

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I understand the basic concept of Lucene/Elastisearch searching which is by reverse indexing built out of words parsed from texts in the documents.

Trying to find out if Lucene/ElasticSearch is good for the following scenario since there are not many "words" to parse in the documents and hence to reverse-index from.

With millions of students, each student may select to take a small subset of tests (currently a thousand of different tests the students can choose from), each test may consist of 100 problems. We want to keep track of student performance with the following document

```
{
    "studentId": <a number>,
    "testId": <a number, ranging from 1 to 1000>,
    "results": [
        "R", "W", "N", .... 
    ]
}
```

Where for each student and each of test he/she takes, the results on each of 100 problems in the tests. The result could be "R" (right), "W" (wrong), "N" (skipped). We allow student to retest on the problems he/she skipped, so the documents will need to be updated.

The searches we may need to run include the following and we want the searches to complete within 1 or 2 seconds.

1. Given a subset of students (could be 100,000 of them, this subset can be arbitrary, so it can't be tagged ahead of time), and given a test, find out for each problems in the test, the number of students did it right.
2. Give a subset of students, for each of the 1000 tests, how many student pass the test (a student passing a test means that he/she did all the problems in the test right)

   We could rearrange the document format if you have a suggestion that helps searching.

Comment: well with elasticsearch you have more the advantage of finding stuff your now knowing IDs of so try to match something. but as i understand your point, you already have the IDs of the documents you are looking for, so ther is no real search because you already know where to look. so I think elasticsearch is kind of overkill and your better with some postgres oder smt like that.

Comment: @RichieK SQL db has their own problem with the potential size of the table and the type of searches we need to perform.  I am just posting it here to find out if it's feasible to do it with Lucene/ElasticSearch.  If it can solve the problem, a overkill is ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ElasticSearch (ES), but it's overkill. Why? ES main advantage is reverse index (and parsing) which you don't need here.

Another advantage which you do need here is scale out (elastic). But - there are many alternatives. You could implement shards for yourself using MySQL life Facebook did (see also [here](https://www.wix.engineering/blog/scaling-to-100m-mysql-is-a-better-nosql)) , or use one of the many many other options available today: redis, Spark, BigQuery, Redshift, Cassandra, (MongoDB?), Hadoop.

Comment: It's interesting idea to do sharding with MySQL. However,  ElasticSearch does seem to have flexibility and extensiblility should we add more fields in the future. I am posting it here to see if it's feasible at all and solicit some experience on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, ElasticSearch is not really elastic - unlike for example Spark. Why? you can add nodes, but you have to wait for lengthy rebalance. BTW - do you have 100k students already , or this is for future growth?

Comment: The lengthy rebalance is not good but not disqualifying either. We have to assume there are 1mm students from day 1.